# Can't locate Connection.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /etc/perl /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 ....) at ./select.cgi at line

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi, httpd.conf, cgi-bin

I am trying my hands for the first time in -> **Apache - Perl (CGI)** on Ubuntu.

The Apache server is working fine in the folder `/var/www` for the default `index.html` file. But since I want to run a CGI script, I also installed (just in case) DBI, as suggested by some forums. I set the permissions for complete access to my `cgi-bin` folder in which the `select.cgi` script resides. I tried tweaking the `select.cgi` script multiple times redirecting the library to the Perl library, but to no avail. I modified the `httpd.conf` file and set the directory path to the `select.cgi` folder. That didn't work. I also defined `ScriptAlias`, and set it to the working directory. That didn't work either.
Does anyone have any helpful pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you gave information that contradicts what you gave originally. The latter information appears to be more reliable, so I'll use it.

I believe you said the path to the module is

```
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/foo/bar/Connection.pm
```

and that the error message you got (with line breaks added) is:

```
Can't locate foo/bar/Connection.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
   /etc/perl
   /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2
   /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2
   /usr/lib/perl5
   /usr/share/perl5 
   /usr/lib/perl/5.14
   /usr/share/perl/5.14
   /usr/local/lib/site_perl
   .
   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/foo/bar/
) at ...
```

You did something like

```
use foo::bar::Connection;
```

or

```
require "foo/bar/Connection.pm";
```

Perl looked for

- `/etc/perl/foo/bar/Connection.pm`
- `/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/foo/bar/Connection.pm`
- ...
- `/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/foo/bar/foo/bar/Connection.pm`

But none of those are

```
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/foo/bar/Connection.pm
```

It's simple to fix. Add the following to your script:

```
use lib '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5';
```

The other possible fix is to use

```
 use Connection;
```

instead of

```
 use foo::bar::Connection;
```

Which fix is the correct fix depends on what that `package` line in side the module looks like. If you find `package foo::bar::Connection;`, you need to modify `@INC` (as shown with `use lib, for example). If you find`package Connection;`, you need to change the`use` directive.

Comment: I am trying to write my comment, but the space of 600 characters is too short, and hence its not allowing me to write my changes and the subsequent errors. Let me try, shortening my response

Comment: @ikegami-I added `BEGIN { push(@INC,'/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2');}`  in my `select.cgi` file. In `5.14.2` ,I have the folders `foo/bar/Connection`. In `select.cgi` script file, I have the lines  `use foo::bar::Connection;`. The errors I got this time were:  `readMainConfFile: ERROR: Searched for a conf file and couldn't find it.  Perhaps you need to create one in /var/www/../conf/foo/psat.conf.  Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/foo/bar/Connection.pm line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/foo/bar/Connection.pm line 15.`

Comment: That new error is unrelated to your original one, and isn't from Perl, but rather from your code or from a module you are using.

Comment: Thanks. Atleast now, I know its not from Perl. I will try to debug this out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

**This is not exact solution that you want but the overall idea is like below.**

How to resolve `Cant locate xxxx.pm in @INC path` problem

By default perl looks for modules in the standard library path and the current directory. 
Sometimes you need to use some modules that are installed in non standard locations; there are several ways to deal with this situation:

To check whether your module is in `@INC` path use.

Example:

```
perl -e 'use SOAP::Lite;'
perl -e 'use Error;'
```

If you run these commands on a system that has `SOAP::Lite` and `Error` installed, Perl will simply return from these commands without printing any output.

To check current standard library path use:

```
perl -le 'print foreach @INC'
```

If you have the administrative privileges, then best solution is to install the module in any of the system defined library path.

Set the environment variable `PERL5LIB`
Perl will look for modules in the directories specified in `PERL5LIB` environment variable before looking in the standard library and current directory. 
So you can set this variable to locate your modules.

Example:

```
# For unix like systems
PERL5LIB=/home/path/lib:/usr/another/path/lib; export PERL5LIB
```

**Note:** separate the directories with colons on unix and with a semicolon on Windows.

IF you are running your code from command line then use `-I` parameter. The syntax should be something like.

```
perl -I /home/path/lib -I /usr/another/lib script.pl
```

And you can also Add the library path in your script

The command for including the path in your script is: use lib `path`.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib "/home/path/lib";
use lib "/usr/another/lib";

use MyCustomModule;
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried the above. Didn't fix it. I don't know, where am I going wrong.